# jQuery loaded through JS in head

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery and jQuery Mobile to build an application. I load jQuery and jQuery Mobile dynamically through a script in the head. My body uses jQuery ($) in a script but cannot access it as it loads asynchronously. How can I load my jQuery in synchronously or approach resolving the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Comment: If you are putting a `script` tag in the head it's not really dynamic - and is definitely synchronous. If you are using an autoloader like `requirejs` it is asynch. How exactly are you putting the script on the page?

Comment: The script is loaded through a script tag, it contains an anonymous function that executes and loads other script tags with jQuery.

Comment: If you load it asynchronously, use something like requirejs.

Comment: I can't use document ready as jQuery mobile pulls each page in asynchronously and then populates the DOM with its body

Comment: this makes 0 sense! Why on earth would uyou be manually loading the in the head using script in the head. why not just add the traditional link?!?!? I use jQuery mobile in all different ways and have never seen a reason to not just add the script taged links

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [head.js](http://headjs.com/). It asynchronously loads your scripts, and then gives you a ready function, similar to jQuery's, where you can put all of your onLoad code.

```
<head>
...
<script src="/js/head.js"></script>
<script>
    head.js('/js/jquery.js', '/js/jquery-mobile.js', function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Write some code!
        })
    });
</script>
...
</head>
```

If you need javascript elsewhere, you can use `head.ready()`

```
<script>
    head.ready(function() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Write more code!
        });
    });
</script>
```

Which can go anywhere in the html.

Note: The head.js examples don't use jQuery's `$(document).ready()` inside of `head.ready()`, but I recall running into some problem without it. They may have fixed it, but including it doesn't really hurt anything.

*Update:* As noted in the comments, for jQuery Mobile, you should use `$(document).bind('pageinit')` in place of `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: I can't use document.ready becuase jQuery mobile will be pulling my pages in asynchronously

Comment: @ubiQ In that case, as the jQuery Mobile docs say, just use `$(document).bind('pageinit')` in place of `$(document).ready()`.